# Mysqli Table not updating

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to edit the data echoed to the html table from a mysqli table
but its not working the data won't update 
it redirected me back to the `editest.php` and nothing changes

**editest.php**

```
<?php

include('dbconn.php');

$query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_locators WHERE accholder_ID='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Cisu/css/footable.core.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Cisu/css/footable.metro.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script src="/Cisu/javascript/jquery/footable.js"></script>
        <script src="/Cisu/javascript/jquery/footable.paginate.js"></script>  
        <script src="/Cisu/javascript/jquery/footable.filter.js"></script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Cisu/css/search.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Cisu/css/footable.editable-1.0.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div id="header">
            <img src="/Cisu/images/sbma.png" class="logo" id="logo"></img>
            <a style = "float:left;">Account Settings</a>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Locators</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
                        <ul class="ul-sidebar">
                <li class="li-sidebar">
                    <a class="active">View Locators</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        <form class="form-style-1">

        <ul class="ul-sidebar">
        <li class="li-sidebar">    <label class="header-label">Company Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="filter"/></li>
</select>
        </ul>
        </form>

        </div>
        <div id="section">
            <table class="footable" data-page-size="3" data-filter="#filter" data-filter-minimum="4"  data-first-text="FIRST" data-next-text="NEXT" data-previous-text="PREVIOUS" data-last-text="LAST">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th> 
                <th>Company Name</th> 
                <th>Nationality</th> 
                <th>Primary Address</th> 
                <th>Industry Code</th>
                <th>TIN</th> 
                <th>Status</th> 
                <th>Employees</th>
                <th>Account Holder ID</th>
                <th>EDIT</th> 
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
            <?php
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;
?>
           <tr>
                <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_ID'];
?></td>
                <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_CompanyName'];
?></td>
                <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_Nationality'];
?></td>
                <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_PrimaryAddress'];
?></td>
                <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_IndustryCode'];
?></td>
                <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_TIN'];
?></td>
                <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_Status'];
?></td>
                <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_Employees'];
?></td>
                <td><?php
    echo $row1['accholder_ID'];
?></td>
                <?php
    echo '<td><a href="editlocator.php?locators_ID=' . $row1[0] . '">Edit</a></td>';
?>

            </tr>
            <?php
endwhile;
?>

            </tbody>

            <!-- the pagination -->
            <!-- hide-if-no-paging = hide the pagination control -->
            <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
            <td colspan="9">
                <div class="pagination"></div>
            </td>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){

           $('.footable').footable();

       });

    </script>

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            S.B.M.A Centralized Information System 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**editlocator.php**

```
    <?php

include("dbconn.php");

function renderForm($id = '', $accid = '', $companyname = '', $nationality = '' , $primaryaddress = '', $industrycode = '', $tin = '', $status = '', $employees = '')
{ 

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <Title>
        EDIT
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/sbma.png" class="logo" id="logo"></img>
            <a style = "float:left;">Account Settings</a>
            <a href="AdminMenu.php">Home</a>
            <a href="DeptMenu.php">Department</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
                    <form class="form-style-1" action="" method="post">
             <ul>
                <fieldset class="fieldset-company">
                <input type="hidden" name="locators_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
                <input type="hidden" name="accholder_ID" value="<?php echo $accid; ?>" />
                <p>Account ID: <?php echo $accid; ?></p>            
                    <li>
                        <label>Company Name</label>
                        <input type='text' name='companyname' id='companyname' maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $companyname; ?>"/>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label>Nationality</label>
                        <input type='text' name='nationality' id='nationality' maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $nationality; ?>"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Primary Address</label>
                        <input type='text' name='primaryaddress' id='primaryaddress' maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $primaryaddress; ?>"/>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label>Industry Code:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='industrycode' id='industrycode' maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $industrycode; ?>"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>TIN:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='tin' id='tin' maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $tin; ?>"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Status:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='status' id='status' maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $status; ?>"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Employees:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='employees' id='employees' maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $employees; ?>"/>
                    </li>
                    </fieldset>

                         <li>
                      <input type='Submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
                         </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="section">


            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
    S.B.M.A Centralized Information System 
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php }

// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['locators_ID']))
{
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
// make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
if (is_numeric($_POST['locators_ID']))
{
// get variables from the URL/form
$id = $_POST['locators_ID'];
$accid = $row1['accholder_ID'];
$companyname = htmlentities($_POST['locators_CompanyName'], ENT_QUOTES);
$nationality = htmlentities($_POST['locators_Nationality'], ENT_QUOTES);
$primaryaddress = $_POST['locators_PrimaryAddress'];
$industrycode = htmlentities($_POST['locators_IndustryCode'], ENT_QUOTES);
$tin = htmlentities($_POST['locators_TIN'], ENT_QUOTES);
$status = $_POST['locators_Status'];
$employees = htmlentities($_POST['locators_Employee'], ENT_QUOTES);


if ($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE tbl_locators SET locators_CompanyName = ?, locators_Nationality = ?, locators_PrimaryAddress=?, locators_IndustryCode =?, locators_TIN =?, locators_Status=?, locators_Employee =?
WHERE locators_ID=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("issssssi", $id, $companyname, $nationality, $primaryaddress, $industrycode, $tin, $status, $employees, $accid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error message if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirect the user once the form is updated
header("Location: editest.php");
}
// if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
else
{
echo "ID VARIABLE NOT VALID!";
}
}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
else
{
// make sure the 'id' value is valid
if (is_numeric($_GET['locators_ID']) && $_GET['locators_ID'] > 0)
{
// get 'id' from URL
$id = $_GET['locators_ID'];

// get the recod from the database
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_locators WHERE locators_ID=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $companyname, $nationality, $primaryaddress, $industrycode, $tin, $status, $employees, $accid);
$stmt->fetch();


// show the form
renderForm($id, $accid, $companyname, $nationality, $primaryaddress, $industrycode, $tin, $status, $employees);

$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
}
}
// if the 'locators_ID' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page
else
{
header("Location: editest.php");
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Number of placeholder not equal to bind statement!!

Comment: @Saty are you talking about the $accid?

Comment: @JK.Constantine you have a different number of `?` in your query than the number of params in the `bindParam` statement. This will lead to an error and the query will not get executed

Comment: @Lelio Faieta so i tried removing the `$accid` in the `bindParam`
but it still not working

Comment: @JK.Constantine that's not the issue! I count 10 params and 7 ? on a rough check. You need to have the same number of params and placeholders

Comment: Well, some particular typo aside, the essential answer to a question "Mysqli Table not updating" is "How to report mysqli error"